# How to add foreign key constraint in rails which is not have id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-migrations

I have a model User and there we have primary_key as user_id instead of id, I know I should use id for primary_key but clients wants we should use user_id instead of id.

I have a other table and I have to relate that table with user_id

I am adding migration like this for other table:

```
t.references :user,             index: true, foreign_key: true
```

But when I run the migration i get an error related to foreign key constraints like:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
     ALTER TABLE "user_devices" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e700a96826"
    FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
      REFERENCES "users" ("id")

It seems rails default try to point other table with id column but I have user_id in users table.

So how can I add foreign key constraints like:

```
 ALTER TABLE "user_devices" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e700a96826"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("user_id")
```

with rails migrations?

Answer (score 12):

You can create a separate migration like this:

```
add_column :user_devices,:user_id,:integer
add_foreign_key :user_devices, :users, column: :user_id, primary_key: "user_id"
```

Comment: Yes I got the solution as well on 
document http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key

add_foreign_key :user_devices, :users, column: :user_id, primary_key: :user_id